# ServiceBusConfiguration class is missing in webjobs .net core 3.1 what is alternative class

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-webjobs

ServiceBusConfiguration is missing in latest framework webjobs in .net core 3.1. what is alternative class for this.?

Answer (score 1):

- In Azure WebJobs .NetCore 3.1 Project, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` is deprecated , an alternative package  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` has been added.
  [image]
- `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`  - This package let's you to use
  `ServiceBusConfiguration serviceBusConfig = new ServiceBusConfiguration();`
  [image]
- You will get an error `Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.`
- To Resolve the issue , add

```cs
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.30"/>
```

manually in your .csproj file.

. You need  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` to use  ServiceBusConfiguration.

[image]

Comment: @Dhanaraj Jogihalli, do let me know if the information provided helped you in solving your problem ?